# npm: not found error in gitlab-ci.yml file while executing test cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to test my test-cases of nodeJs.

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
test:
  type: test
  script:
    - npm run test
```

while executing CI/CD I got this error

> /bin/sh: eval: line 117: npm: not found

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 7):

You should specify that you want to use the `node` image

```
test:
  image: node:10
  type: test
  script:
    - npm run test
```